# PHP read file vs SQL efficiency

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the most efficient way of finding out "true/false" in PHP between finding if a file exists, and running a query for a "true" statement?

For instance, a daemon script running every second that attempts to find if a condition is true/false. If true, it can either store it in the DB, or create a filename called something like "condition.param.true"

Let's say 1,000 other scripts are attempting to find the same condition every few seconds. As it's faster to have a "control bot" find the conditions, then report back true/false, all these scripts need to do is see if the file exists, or if the DB contains "true"

Which of these methods would be fastest and cause less server lag?

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "True";
}
```

Or

```
Query($params);
if ($result == 'true') {
    echo "True";
}
```

Comment: Given that they're doing completely different things, they're not exactly analogous.... but why don't you test them and see, especially as the answer will depend almost entirely on your own system.... db on another server introduces a lag, but db result caching can improve things for regular queries against the same data

Comment: You can just measure it. It's not the sort of micro-optimization that's worth worrying about, initially.

Answer (score 0):

There is overhead to both methods, and as Mark Baker comments above, there are conditions specific to your server and architecture that could make either the file solution or the SQL solution better.

Fastest of all would be to use RAM instead, and that means a cache.

So I would store the fact in the SQL database, and then also cache the information in [memcached](https://memcached.org/).

If you want to get a better feel for performance estimation, you should study http://highscalability.com/numbers-everyone-should-know and understand the orders of magnitude of performance difference of the types of actions you can do in a computer.